# Facing Flutter Apk issue that not showing any pages

Tags: flutter, apk, release

I've developed a Flutter app but when I create its `apk`, it's run perfectly on first installation and after that I close my app and rerun then it is not showing any pages.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check the logs to see what is happening. Use [Logcat extreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex) for checking the logs on your android device.